# Resizeable element border

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, border, children

I got a div named "content". All the children divs of "content" is resizeble and gets a border on hover like so:

```
$('#content div').resizable({});
$('#content div').mouseleave(function(){
$(this).removeClass('borderClass');
});
$('#content div').mouseenter(function(){
$(this).addClass('borderClass');
});
```

The problem is that a border around the sides of the resizeable element appears.
Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/hyEhh/6/

How can i give all the children of "content" a border except the borders that appears on the sidelines when you risize the div??

EDIT* I must be able to add borders dynamically with javascript/jQuery. This fiddle is just an example, i want to be able to add borders on hover regardless how many divs ther are in "content"

One thing that I have tried that I don't understand why didn't work is this:

```
if(document.body.style.cursor = "n-resize") {
        $(this).removeClass('borderClass');
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/hyEhh/7/

Comment: so you want "content" to have a border but not "test"?

Comment: pls clarify your question as we are clearly all making different assumptions about what it is that you actually would like to achieve.

Comment: I have updated the question now, do you now understand what i am aiming for?

Comment: ok so u want a top and bottom border to be added to the element of whatever resizable element the user is currently hovering over? and no other borders added to anything else?

Comment: If you look at the fiddle it seems like all resizeable elements gets some kinda of div assigned to them. So when you hover over the sideline of a div that lets you resize that div, those sidelines gets their own border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is basicaly the resizeable div that is creating the border since resizble adds another div to it dynamically (inspect your element) ...and your selector is for all the div inside `#content`. one way to do this is call all your element that you need hover sepearately... or other way leave all the div that was created by resizeable in your selector....

try this

```
    $('#content div').resizable({});

$('div#test,div#test2').hover(function(){
     $(this).addClass('borderClass');
    },function(){

         $(this).removeClass('borderClass');
    });
```

and use `hover()` instead of two seperate event handler... hover is shorthand for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

**updated**

```
 $('#content div:not(".ui-resizable-handle")').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('borderClass');
    },function(){

        $(this).removeClass('borderClass');
    });
```

this is without selecting the div that resized created dynamically.. nothing needs to be added in your HTML simply use the jquery `not` method...

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hyEhh/8/#update) 
[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hyEhh/11/)

Comment: i want to be able to add borders on hover regardless how many divs ther are in "content"

Comment: then other way is give all your div a class.. and call that class selector ... fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/hyEhh/10/ .. then the number of div won't matter.. just that the div should have a  same class

Comment: Well allmost something like that, but ill have to add the the class .test dynamically to it then and that brings us back to the original problem of adding a class to all children except those borders

Comment: @Koiski ok then.. i will give you the first way of doing this.. select all div without the resized created div... here you go using `not` ... http://jsfiddle.net/hyEhh/11/ ..check my updated answer too

Answer (score 0):

Add a common class name to each element on which you want a border.

```
<div id=content>
    <div id=test>BLABLA
        <div class="child" id="test2">lala</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then match the CSS selector you're using in jQuery:

```
$('#content div').resizable({});
$('#content div.child').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('borderClass');
});
$('#content div.child').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).addClass('borderClass');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

theres a couple of ways to do this.
first way would be to assign a class to your children and call it like this,

```
<div id=content>
    <div id=test>BLABLA
        <div class="className" id="test2">lala</div>
    </div>
</div>

$('#content div').resizable({});
$('#content div').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.className').removeClass('borderClass');
});
$('#content div').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.className').addClass('borderClass');
});
```

second would be to search for the elements that are children of the parent div.

```
$('#content div').resizable({});
$('#content div').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).children().removeClass('borderClass');
});
$('#content div').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).children().addClass('borderClass');
});
```

if you want to add a border to just the single resizable element you are hovering over it's very simple. you can assign the elements a class as mentioned, select them using this class, and bind the click event to it.

```
<div id=content>
    <div id=test>BLABLA
        <div class="className">lala</div>
        <div class="className">lala</div>
        <div class="className">lala</div>
        <div class="className">lala</div>
    </div>
</div>

$('.className').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('borderClass');
});
```

Notice i used the toggleclass method here because it will achieve the same result as adding and removing the class in separate lines.

to achieve having only the top and bottom border your css class should look something like

```
.borderClass
{
border-top:2px solid #000000;
border-right:none;
border-bottom:2px solid #000000;
border-left:none;
}
```

Comment: That should be `$(this).find('.className')` Otherwise you'll be adding borders to random elements.

Comment: @redolent you're not entirely correct, nor entirely incorrect. I see your point, but the point I am making is that the inputs that should have the click event bound to them should have a common class only used on those elements. This allows the use of a class as a selector with nothing else. Of course if OP decided to assign that class to a bunch of other random inputs then yes, it would select those other ones as well.

Comment: If you look at the fiddle it seems like all resizeable elements gets some kinda of div assigned to them. So when you hover over the sideline of a div that lets you resize that div, those sidelines gets their own border